Is it possible in Google Sheets to get cells to fill automatically after filling one cell with a forumula?
Maybe this is a standard thing to do but I can't figure it out without getting myself into a recursive pickle.
Anyway, I have a Google form that collects data to a spreadsheet.
Let's say, a person gets the form and they state their preferred name, their favourite car, their favourite genre of fan fiction, and they share their best limerick.
in this example, in the tab that receives the raw data, which I'll call raw_tab, preferred name is in b2, car is in c2, their favourite genre of fan fiction is in d2, and limerick is in e2.
Their responses are Bob, VW, CBS News, and a bawdy limerick
I review that raw data and, based on Bob's responses, I think it is best for them to go into group 1.
I then go to cell F5 in the tab I'll call group1_tab and I enter =raw_tab!b2 into it.
Outwardly I can see "Bob" in that cell but the other cells see the formula.
The other cells look at that formula in f5 and fill themselves in based on that formula.
If I want group1_tab cell j4 to show the person's favourite genre of fan fiction, can it look at the contents of cell f5 (=raw_tab!b2) and then write that same formula but change b2 to d2 by incrementing the b to d but leaving the number alone?
In my head cell j4 would read something like =f5 but take the letter you find there and "add" 2 but leave the number you find there the same.
I need to be able to copy and paste this configuration so I can use of for multiple people represented on group1_tab by entering one a new value in say f20, then f35 etc. without having to recode each cell to look at f20 and then f35 etc.
Is this possible?
I've tried a lot of recursive stuff and can't find a way to acheive this other than copying and pasting and then modifiying for each new entry in group1_tab.

Look for vlookup(), xlookup(), filter(), query() functions.

How's this for a quick-and-dirty idea: 1) new tab, create a list of Group Names. 2) Form Responses tab, use a spare column: header = "Group Name". 3) Write a script triggered by a new submission to update the Data Validation for the cell in the "Group Name" column (create a dropdown based on "Group Names" tab). 4) For Bob's response, select "Group 1" from the dropdown. 5) For reporting, on a new tab, create a "Group Names" dropdown as a variable, and a query/filter/whatever on the raw data with the dropdown as a criterion.
